# How to stretch a material without changing shape

Tags: materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I am completely new to blender and I am trying to make a 3d brick wall. Ive tried various ways but I could not make it realistic(I tried uw wrapping method but still didnt look good). Finally I found a way, which was to put the material(I found online) on a plane and then joined it on the 3d object. My problem is that when I try to scale it sideways, the material stretches as well. How do I strech it without making it stretch the material as well? 
This is how it is before stretching:[image]
and This is how it is when I scale it sideways
[image]
Please tell me how to solve this, I have been stuck on this for a week. I apologise if I have made any mistake, I am new to blender, please go easy on me

Comment: Have you tried to re-unwrap your plane, or change the UV proportions in the UV Editor?

Comment: You will need to re uv unwrap the plane. Or you need to use additional material node "mapping" to fix the aspect ration

Comment: sorry really new to this, how do I re uv unwrap? can please show in steps?

Comment: [Here are some detailed steps](http://sophiehoulden.com/tutorials/blender/unwrapTut.html).

Comment: Just learned it and it works!! thank you so much. Unrelated question, do you know any tutorials to make the tiles or brick images extrude, right now its just on a smooth plane, is there any way for it to jut out to make it look like a real 3d brick wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

-Go into edit mode

-Press GG to Edge Slide

-On bottom menu Toggle "Correct UVs"

-Resize using GG without breaking textures (hold alt to extend outside the borders)

Comment: This works as well, thank you so much!! Unrelated question, do you know any tutorials to make the tiles or brick images extrude, right now its just on a smooth plane, is there any way for it to jut out to make it look like a real 3d brick wall?

Comment: Search for "Blender displacement map tutorials" its pretty taxing on GPU but you can achieve really good looking brick textures that way :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help